# RestSharp - C#: result is null and response JSON has validation errors - username and password are null

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, restsharp

When debugged result is null and response giving username and Password as null inspite of passing them, can someone please help me

```
    public static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var options = new RestClient("https://example.com");
        IAuthenticator auth = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");
        //var client = new RestClient(options);
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/w1/Auth", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\" }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var responseJson = options.Execute(request).Content;
        //var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["access_token"].ToString();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseJson);
        var token = result.access_token;
        return token;
    }
```

Expecting access token.

Comment: I don't see where you use the `auth` variable in the RestRequest instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 var options = new RestClient("https://example.com");
 var request = new RestRequest("/api/v1/Auth", Method.Post); \\ <--- v1
 request.AddJsonBody(new
 {
     username = "Username",
     password = "YourPassword"
 }); \\ <-- no extra headers, easier life
 
 var responseJson = options.Execute(request).Content;
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseJson);
 var token = result.access_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this being said, I created a solution in .Net Core 6.0 where I used `HttpClient` instead of `RestClient` and I think that this might help you in your predicament.

**Explanation of Code**

*(note: It is expected that each of these classes outside of the `main()` method should be located in it's own folder / `namespace` structure)*

The `ObjectExtensions` `static` `class` contains extension methods for converting objects into JSON objects and checking if a `string` is `null` or empty.

The `UsernamePasswordStruct` `struct` contains the `JsonProperty` tag ( note: need to install `Newtonsoft.Json` from the `NuGet Package Manager` inside of Visual Studio to use the `JsonProperty` tag or the `JsonConvert` static helper class ) that allows us to map our struct's properties into a JSON object.

The `Client` `static` `class` is where your code for your `HttpClient` will exist. In here, we have methods for your `/api/v1/Auth` endpoint and how you can create the `HttpRequestMesssage` , `HttpResponseMessage` , and how you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()` to return your JSON Object back to the user.

**Explanation of Main() Program**

The `main()` program contains code where we provide our desired 'username' and 'password' values and we pass those values into our `await ChameleonVisionClient.PostAuthenticationAsync()` method. If a value is returned from that method, then the program will complete successfully. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

I hope this helps you.

**ALL CODE**

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ZvjezdanVCode1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static Class that contains extensions for objects
    /// </summary>
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts any object into a JSON Object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>JSON Object (string) </returns>
        public static string ConvertToJson(this object value, bool withFormatting = false)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, withFormatting ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if our string value is null or empty
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns 'true' if our string object is deemed as 'null' or empty. Otherwise, returns 'false'.</returns>
        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length.Equals(0);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Struct that contains our 'username' and 'password' JSON Properties
    /// </summary>
    public struct UsernamePasswordStruct
    {
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        internal string UserName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]
        internal string Password { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Our Chameleon Vision Client that we can use for all APIs
    /// </summary>
    public static class Client
    {
        // used for thread-locking
        private readonly static object _lockObject = new object();

        // our API client itself
        private static HttpClient client;

        static ChameleonVisionClient()
        {
            // used for locking our thread so 1 thread can access our locked method at a time
            lock(_lockObject)
            {
                if(client is null)
                {
                    client = GetClient();
                }
            }
        }

        private static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return client;
        }

        public static void AddAuthenticationToClient(string type, string token, bool withTokenOverride = false)
        {
            lock(_lockObject)
            {
                if(client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization is null || withTokenOverride)
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(type, token);
                }
            }
        }

        private static HttpRequestMessage PostAuthenticationRequest(UsernamePasswordStruct userNamePassword)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> userInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
                { "username", userNamePassword.UserName },
                { "password", userNamePassword.Password }
            };

            return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/v1/Auth")
            {
                Content = new StringContent(userInfo.ConvertToJson(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }

        public static async Task<string> PostAuthenticationAsync(UsernamePasswordStruct userNamePassword)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = PostAuthenticationRequest(userNamePassword);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to execute our POST v1 Auth Endpoint.\nResponse:\n{response.ConvertToJson()}");
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            UsernamePasswordStruct myInfo = new UsernamePasswordStruct()
            {
                UserName = "Enter_Username_Here",
                Password = "Enter_Password_Here"
            };

            string authenticationValue = await ChameleonVisionClient.PostAuthenticationAsync(myInfo);

            if(authenticationValue.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                throw new Exception("PostAuthenticationAsync() failed to return a result");
            }

            /* Next Steps
             *  1) Get the string value from 'result' and then create another object so you can deserialize your JSON object into a C# struct
             *  2) You can, then, call the ChameleonVisionClient.AddAuthenticationToClient("Basic", your_auth_token_value_here)
             *  3) You can use your HttpClient for whichever API endpoint you wish to use
             */
        }
    }
}
```